# glDrawElements fails with error GL_INVALID_OPERATION

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, opengl-3

My goal is to get instanced rendering working, however even a single `glDrawElements` fails right now. Note: This code already works on Windows. However on OS X it fails with `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`

Basically I load up all the static data into buffers, and then the last buffer contains dynamic data which I reload before every draw. I then call glDrawElementsInstanced (or for debugging `glDrawElements`) which promptly fails. I know because there's an error print before, and after that call, and it always prints out an OpenGL error. (Even with `glDrawElements`) This error does not appear if I use `glDrawArrays` instead

Please see the comments in the code for some additional information. Any help is extremely appreciated.

```
//Setup code, at this point vertices,textureCoordiantes,normals are all populated

//Allocate the space for the gpu buffers now
//and send the static data
//Rebind the array to bring them into the current context
glBindVertexArray ( vertexArray );

//Push voxel to gpu
glBindBuffer ( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer );
glBufferData ( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 36*sizeof(vec3), vertices, GL_STATIC_READ );
glEnableVertexAttribArray ( shader->AttributeVertex() );
glVertexAttribPointer ( shader->AttributeVertex(), 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0 );

glBindBuffer ( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureBuffer );
glBufferData ( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 36*sizeof(vec2), textureCoordinates, GL_STATIC_READ );
glEnableVertexAttribArray ( shader->AttributeTexture() );
glVertexAttribPointer ( shader->AttributeTexture(), 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0 );

glBindBuffer ( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalBuffer );
glBufferData ( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 36*sizeof(vec3), normals, GL_STATIC_READ );
glEnableVertexAttribArray ( shader->AttributeNormal() );
glVertexAttribPointer ( shader->AttributeNormal(), 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0 );
//Allocate space for positions
glBindBuffer ( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer );
glBufferData ( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, INSTANCE_RENDER_SWEEP*sizeof(vec4), positions, GL_DYNAMIC_READ );
glEnableVertexAttribArray ( shader->AttributePosition() );
glVertexAttribPointer ( shader->AttributePosition(), 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0 ); 


    //This code runs a bit later, but runs over and over:
    //indices is a vector<GLuint> of length 36 and is just 0-35

glBindVertexArray ( vertexArray );
glBindBuffer ( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer );
glBufferSubData ( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0,INSTANCE_RENDER_SWEEP*sizeof(vec4), positions );
glEnableVertexAttribArray ( shader->AttributePosition() );
glVertexAttribPointer ( shader->AttributePosition(), 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0 ); 

//The position is per-instance
//everything else is per-vertex
glVertexAttribDivisor(shader->AttributeNormal(),0);
glVertexAttribDivisor(shader->AttributePosition(),1);
glVertexAttribDivisor(shader->AttributeTexture(),0);
glVertexAttribDivisor(shader->AttributeVertex(),0);

cout << "1Err: " << glGetError() << "\n";
    glDrawDelements(GL_TRIANGLES,36,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,&indices[0]);
//glDrawElementsInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &indices[0], bufferedVoxels);
    //This next error prints out 1282 which is GL_INVALID_OPERATION
    //However if i replace the above with glDrawArrays, it works for one instance (no error)
cout << "2Err: " << glGetError() << "\n";
//All buffered voxels now drawn
bufferedVoxels = 0;
```

Comment: What sort of OpenGL context are you using on OS X at the moment? Core 3.2+? Instancing is GL 3.x era, to use it in the unextended form on OS X you need a Core profile. Any function that is only exposed in Core that you try to call from the GL 2.1 context will either silently fail or product `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` on OS X. This makes it different from other platforms, where if the function is not supported you know this because the function pointer will be NULL.

Answer (score 1):

With a GL core context, you cannot pass a client-side array for the `indices` parameter of `glDrawElements` or `glDrawElementsInstanced`. In both cases, you need to create an index buffer and storing your indices in this buffer. The `indices` parameter of the draw call then becomes the offset (in bytes) into the bound index buffer from which to read the indices.

However, seeing as your indices array is simply 0 - 35, why not use `glDrawArrays` or `glDrawArraysInstanced` instead?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too experienced with openGL, but are you using glew? If so, did you try setting `glewExperimental = GL_TRUE` before `glewInit()` ?

Comment: GLEW is not necessary on OS X. Apple has always done things differently, and their way of doing GL is a little tricky as explained in my comment to the OP's question.